# Observer / Observable to PropertyChangeListener

Tags: java

Using Observer and Observable method update() would look as following:

```
@Override
    public void update( Observable o, Object arg ) {
        switch( (GameState) arg )
        {
            case NEW_GAME:
                setNewGame();
                break;

            case CHECK:
                setGameCheck( (Model) o );
                break;
        }
    }
```

I want to replace it with PropertyChangeListener since Observer and Observable are deprecated. I don't know how to update depending on GameState.
Btw is there an equivalent of notifyObserver in PropertyChangeListener?

Comment: PropertyChangeListener is the observer. It has no need of a "notify observer" method since it _is_ the observer.

Comment: I meant notify observer in a class that in Observer / Obsrvable pattern is the one that extends Observable.

In this case I would do it as following: notifyObservers(GameState.NEW_GAME).

Comment: It's not necessary here because the PropertyChangeListener is called whenever the bound property changes. I'm assuming you already read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html)?

Comment: Okay, now I understand. Thanks!